# Select / highlight every second pair in UserForm listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am wondering is there any solution to select / highlight every second pair in the list with some piece of code?

I have sat up listbox to MultiSelect:

[image]

And I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

By clicking button on UserForm:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Select every second pair

End Sub
```

I have tried to play with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

' Select every second pair

sameCustomerComparison.Selected(1) = True
sameCustomerComparison.Selected(2) = True

sameCustomerComparison.Selected(5) = True
sameCustomerComparison.Selected(6) = True

End Sub
```

but it is giving an error... debugger pointing at `sameCustomerComparison.Selected(1) = True`

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'pair'?

Comment: Like select rows/items 1 and 2, then 5 and 6, then  9 and 10 etc

Comment: "but it is giving an error..." Could you be more precise? What error and where?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a list box named `sameCustomerComparison` on that form? Try typing `Me.s` Does this list box name appears in the drop down list? If it exists, is it loaded at the moment of running the code?

Comment: Yes, it should have been `sameCustomerComparison.lstSelectorComparison.Selected(1) = True` but loop is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this simply with a loop

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    With Me.ListBox1
        .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1 Step 4
            If i <= .ListCount Then .Selected(i) = True
            If i + 1 <= .ListCount Then .Selected(i + 1) = True
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: As always, loving the display!